# How can I list the roles defined in a fabfile?

Tags: python, fabric

I defined several roles in my fabfile [env.rolesdef](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/env.html?highlight=roles#roledefs). How can I list the roles with the `fab` command line tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible out of the box, but you can write a simple task:

```
@task
def show_roles():
    for key, value in sorted(env.roledefs.items()):
        print key, value
```

Call it like this:

```
fab show_roles

dev-server ['devel1', 'devel2', ...]
dev-server-root ['root@...', ..]
dev-systems <function get_roledefs_dev at 0x22bc230>
....
```